# Print pixel values where images differ with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

Is there an easy way to print the pixel value where two images differ using imagemagick?

To be clear, I want to know what the value of that pixel is, as well as its coordinate. It doesn't matter from which image, since I can simply swap them to get the right one.

Comment: If they differ, there will be 2 values. Which one do you want? Or do you want the difference? Do you mean a potentially enormous list of text for output?

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's silly, either one is fine. If I want the pixel for image A, then I make sure image A is the one pixels are being printed for. If I want for both, then I run it twice, inverting images. And, yes, a potentially enormous list of text for output. If I wanted `compare`, I'd use `compare`.

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick 6, you can do the following to list the coordinates where the two images differ:

```
convert image1 image2 -compose difference -composite -threshold 0 txt: | tail -n +2 | grep "white" | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/://g'
```

If using Imagemagick 7, change convert to magick

ADDITION:

If you want both the coordinates and the color in one of the two images, then assuming the image has no perfect black pixels, you can do the following:

```
convert image1 image2 \
\( -clone 0,1 -compose difference -composite -threshold 0 \) \
-delete 1 \
-compose multiply -composite txt: |\
 tail -n +2 | grep -v "black" | awk '{print $1,$4}'
```

For example, I take the lena image and put a blue square in the top left corner to make a second image.

Input:

[image]

```
convert lena.png \( -clone 0 -size 5x5 xc:blue -composite \) \
\( -clone 0,1 -compose difference -composite -threshold 0 \) \
-delete 1 \
-compose multiply -composite txt: |\
 tail -n +2 | grep -v "black" | awk '{print $1,$4}'
```

Results:

```
0,0: srgb(226,137,124)
1,0: srgb(224,137,130)
2,0: srgb(225,135,121)
3,0: srgb(228,134,121)
4,0: srgb(227,138,125)
0,1: srgb(226,137,124)
1,1: srgb(224,137,131)
2,1: srgb(225,135,121)
3,1: srgb(228,134,121)
4,1: srgb(227,138,126)
0,2: srgb(226,138,124)
1,2: srgb(224,136,127)
2,2: srgb(225,135,120)
3,2: srgb(228,134,121)
4,2: srgb(227,137,121)
0,3: srgb(228,137,122)
1,3: srgb(225,134,114)
2,3: srgb(225,134,118)
3,3: srgb(229,132,112)
4,3: srgb(227,133,113)
0,4: srgb(224,130,109)
1,4: srgb(223,132,110)
2,4: srgb(224,132,116)
3,4: srgb(226,131,112)
4,4: srgb(226,134,117)
```

If you do have black and the images have no transparency, then you can do:

```
convert image1 image2 \
\( -clone 0,1 -compose difference -composite -threshold 0 \) \
-delete 1 \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
-background black -alpha background txt: |\
 tail -n +2 | grep -v "none" | awk '{print $1,$4}'
```

For example:

```
convert lena.png \( -clone 0 -size 5x5 xc:blue -composite \) \
\( -clone 0,1 -compose difference -composite -threshold 0 \) \
-delete 1 \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
-background black -alpha background txt: |\
 tail -n +2 | grep -v "none" | awk '{print $1,$4}'
```

Results:

```
0,0: srgba(226,137,124,1)
1,0: srgba(224,137,130,1)
2,0: srgba(225,135,121,1)
3,0: srgba(228,134,121,1)
4,0: srgba(227,138,125,1)
0,1: srgba(226,137,124,1)
1,1: srgba(224,137,131,1)
2,1: srgba(225,135,121,1)
3,1: srgba(228,134,121,1)
4,1: srgba(227,138,126,1)
0,2: srgba(226,138,124,1)
1,2: srgba(224,136,127,1)
2,2: srgba(225,135,120,1)
3,2: srgba(228,134,121,1)
4,2: srgba(227,137,121,1)
0,3: srgba(228,137,122,1)
1,3: srgba(225,134,114,1)
2,3: srgba(225,134,118,1)
3,3: srgba(229,132,112,1)
4,3: srgba(227,133,113,1)
0,4: srgba(224,130,109,1)
1,4: srgba(223,132,110,1)
2,4: srgba(224,132,116,1)
3,4: srgba(226,131,112,1)
4,4: srgba(226,134,117,1)
```

Comment: I don't want the difference, nor (only) the coordinate. I want to know exactly what that pixel is, for every pixel that is different.

Comment: What value do you want -- the pixel colors in both images at the given pixel coordinate or just the difference in pixel values?

Comment: I thought I had replied to your comment. I want the pixel color and coordinate in either image (I can run it twice with image order changed), if that pixel color differs between the two images.

Comment: See my ADDITION to my answer to get both the coordinates and colors in one of the two images. Swap the two images to get the other set of coordinates and colors

Comment: Thanks, it does solve the issue, but has the same problem as the other such solution: it is too slow for the scale of the images i have (8k squared), because of all the output imagemagick has to print and then gets discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make two images, both 3px wide and 1px tall:

```
convert xc:red xc:lime xc:blue +append 1.png
```

[image]

```
convert 1.png -flop 2.png
```

[image]

If we do the following, we can make any pixels that are identical in the two images become transparent:

```
convert {1,2}.png -compose changemask -composite mask.png     # Note that {1,2}.png is just bash shorthand for "1.png" "2.png"
```

[image]

And if we re-order the input images:

```
convert {2,1}.png -compose changemask -composite mask.png     # Note that {2,1}.png is just bash shorthand for "2.png" "1.png"
```

[image]

So, I assume you want the above, but in text format with the transparent pixels suppressed:

```
convert {1,2}.png -compose changemask -composite txt: | grep -v ",0)"
```

**Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 3,1,65535,srgba
0,0: (65535,0,0,65535)  #FF0000FF  red
2,0: (0,0,65535,65535)  #0000FFFF  blue
```

Note that if you want to permit a small difference between the images, you can add some *"fuzz-factor"*. So, if you want rgb(0,100,200) to be considered near enough equal to rgb(3,96,205), you could add `-fuzz 5` at the start of the command.

Comment: This does do what I want, but it would be very slow since the images are 8k squared in size, with very few pixels being different. It would take imagemagick a long time to print all these lines that will get discarded. Upvoting because it solves the problem, but not accepting because of the performance issue.